# Search by two unique fields spring boot for uniqueness

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, unique-constraint, spring-repositories

I created a child entity:

```java
public class ChildEntity  {
   private Long bookNo;
   private String bookType;
}
```

Those two fields are together unique. Some kind of data:

```
| No | Type      |
|----|-----------|
| 1  | Classical |
| 2  | Classical |
| 2  | Scifi     |
| 3  | Scifi     |
| 1  | Classical | (Error for uniqueness
```

I created this entity to search inside the parent entity.

```java
public class ParentEntity{
    @ManyToOne
    private ChildEntity child;    
    //and other fields here
}
```

Also, there are 2 different parent entities. They have to be different entity, they have a few different fields. But this child entity is common. So, I will use those child entities to compare / take difference between data tables because only unique areas are in that child entity ones. I can take difference of data tables via that child entity fields.

I made **ManyToOne** because many different parents can have the same child.

I create parent entities in a service like this:

```java
private createParentEntity(Dto dto){
    
    ParentEntity parent = new ParentEntity();
    //set other fields from dto
    parent.setAge(dto.getAge);
    
    ChildEntity child = new ChildEntity();
    child.setBookNo(dto.getBookNo());
    child.setBookType(dto.getBookType());
    
    parent.setChild(child);//here is problem , please look down
}
```

What my problem is, the line  I put a comment.

Same child entities can come, so when I save parents, it will try to save the child again and can get a unique constrain error? What can I do to do this?

Because in the end, I will use spring data to search like this inside parent repository:

```java
parentEntityRepository.findByChild(ChildEntity child);
```

```java
@UniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(
         name = "uq_general_checklist_ordinal",
         columnNames = {"book_no", "book_type"}
    )
}
public class ChildEntity {
   @Id
   private Long bookNo;
    
   @Id
   private String bookType;
}
```

Is that a good solution to put both Ids? Or here, I should first save the child and check if it exists or not?

```java
ChildEntity child =childRepository.findByBookNoAndBookType(
     dto.getBookNo(), 
     dto.getBookType()
);//if exists, set to parent. if not, create new and set it?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this: "Or here, i should first save child and check if exists or not?"

However, instead of saving the child first, just search for a child with the new IDs. This way, you avoid SQL Exceptions. If it doesn't exist, still dont save the child. Add it to the parent and save the parent. It will consequently save the child. If it exists, add it to the new parent and save the parent.

Comment: So, for child entity, you suggest to put 3. field as id column?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question, but I understood that what you call ChildEntity might have more than one Parent. If you're now asking about putting ChildEntity id in Parent, yes, it would work with the same approach in my answer. However, even when you just add the ChildEntity itself, Hibernate will just use an ID column in the Parent.

Comment: I have two columns in child now, bookno, booktype. You suggest do have id as 3. column?

Comment: No! Because parents can have the same child, the child should be referenced in the Parent. Either by a Child object as you have it or by a child ID.

Answer (score 0):

Unless when I want to make heavy use of Hibernate's first level caching and such, my goto approach for tight One-to-Many scenarios has become to make this a unidirectional relationship but except for the loading part take all responsibility out of Hibernate's hands and just do it myself.

That makes it predictable and saves a lot of time in fiddling around with Hibernate and resulting problems with other conventions, peoples' assumptions and other frameworks (e.g. recursive toString,equals,hashcode methods when you have them autogenerated / not carefully crafted).

For this I use:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

at the parent and just the plain id column at the child.

Comment: How will i insert child objects? Because I will receive parent objects, so maybe new child objects can receive from those parents?

Comment: @msadasjwd you have a separate dao/repository for the child objects and insert them explicitly via that. You can retrieve the parent with the current childs via parentRepository.findAllById(1), then determine you need to add a child because it's not there yet, construct it with a reference to the parent's primary key - as, say, child5 - and insert it into the database via childRepository.save(child5).

Comment: Yes, seperate repository for child. So, to compare 2 parent entities ,  first i should get child id from child repository via those two fields. Than, with parent repository, i will search with that id like `parentrepository.findAllByChildEntityId(Long id)`